# gradle files for cordova android application

Tags: cordova, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

When we create a native android studio project, it would generate tow `build.gradle` files, one is `Project:ProjectName` level, and another is `Module:app` level. But when I am importing a cordova android project to android studio, I got two Module level build.gradle files(`Module:CordovaLib`, `Module:android`), no Project level build.gradle found.

I am going to use firebase servers in my cordova project, the official tutorial shows that I have to add pieces of code to both **project level** build.gradle and **module level** build.gradle. I am unable to find out where the project level build.gradle file is.

Any idea for such situation?

Comment: Also, in the module level build.gradle, it says `GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!`, what should I do if I want to add dependencies to the file? I have tried just add dependencies within this gradle file, but the app crashed after installation.

Comment: Did you find any solution for accessing the project level build.gradle file ?

Comment: @Shongsu Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix Finally we use `cordova-plugin-fcm` instead. https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Answer (score 1):

For versions after 7.+ cordova there is only one `build.gradle` which is in `/platforms/android/build.gradle` path. There is no `build.gradle` file in `/platforms/android/app/build.gradle` path.